# eigen_centrality{igraph} crashes R

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to use the `eigen_centrality{igraph}` to calculate the Eigenvector Centrality scores of the nodes in a network. Every time I run the command, though, `Rstudio` crashes. I've also tried this in plain `R` but it crashes as well.

I am using Windows 10. I've already tried reinstalling the library without success.

```
library(igraph)

# sample graph
  g <- sample_gnp(10, 2/10); E(g)$weight <- runif(ecount(g))

# get eigen centrality
  eigen <- eigen_centrality(g, directed = T, weights = E(g)$weight, scale = T)
```

It also crashes when I use the example provided in the library documentation

```
# Generate some test data
  g <- make_ring(10, directed=FALSE)

# Compute eigenvector centrality scores
  eigen_centrality(g)
```

### additional info:

I'm having the same problem on mac os and wanted to bump this question. I also removed and reinstalled `igraph` without luck.

```
$ R
R> library(igraph)
R> #Generate some test data
R> g <- make_ring(10, directed=FALSE)
R> #Compute eigenvector centrality scores
R> eigen_centrality(g)
Fortran runtime error: Insufficient number of elements in TARRAY.
$
$ echo $?
2
$
$ R
R> library(igraph)
R> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] igraph_1.2.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2  magrittr_1.5    pkgconfig_2.0.2
R> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin13.4.0                
system         x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.2                         
year           2017                        
month          09                          
day            28                          
svn rev        73368                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
nickname       Short Summer                
R>
```

Comment: I've used the code again today (20200315) and it works fine. It seems some update to `igraph` have fixed the problem, so I'm closing this question

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on my 4GB pc on window 8. Shows the following output
`eigen_centrality(g)`

```
     $vector
         [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
    
    $value
    [1] 2
    
    $options
    $options$bmat
    [1] "I"
    
    $options$n
    [1] 10
    
    $options$which
    [1] "LA"
    
    $options$nev
    [1] 1
    
    $options$tol
    [1] 0
    
    $options$ncv
    [1] 0
    
    $options$ldv
    [1] 0
    
    $options$ishift
    [1] 1
    
    $options$maxiter
    [1] 1000
    
    $options$nb
    [1] 1
    
    $options$mode
    [1] 1
    
    $options$start
    [1] 1
    
    $options$sigma
    [1] 0
    
    $options$sigmai
    [1] 0
    
    $options$info
    [1] 0
    
    $options$iter
    [1] 5
    
    $options$nconv
    [1] 1
    
    $options$numop
    [1] 17
    
    $options$numopb
    [1] 0
    
    $options$numreo
    [1] 14
```

Check your memory allocated to R by using this command: `memory.limit()`.

Comment: Thanks @Alex but I don't think it's a memory issue. The command `memory.limit()` returns 16298 (16GB) and it still crashes